How to make Idiomatic calls to C code generator, within `build.zig`
I am feeling my way through a project that combines gSOAP with Zig: starting with 100% C then replacing it piece by piece with Zig.
Central to the project is using the gSOAP WSDL to C code generator. The Makefile paragraph to drive it is:
gen: addition.wsdl
    mkdir -p $@
    wsdl2h ./$< -c  -o $@/addition.h
    soapcpp2 -c -r -dgen/ $@/addition.h

The following piece of Zig is equivalent, but given it is so much larger, and must include code to ensure the order of command execution, I wonder - is there an easier and more idiomatic means of creating a subdirectory and then running two code generators in order?
    // Generate gSOAP artefacts
    {
        const wsdl_input = "addition.wsdl";
        const gen_step = b.step("gen", "Generate gSOAP artefacts");

        const gen_run0 = b.addSystemCommand(&.{ "mkdir", "-p", generated_sources });
        const gen_run1 = b.addSystemCommand(&.{ "wsdl2h", wsdl_input, "-c", "-o", generated_sources ++ "/addition.h" });
        const gen_run2 = b.addSystemCommand(&.{ "soapcpp2", "-c", "-r", "-d" ++ generated_sources, generated_sources ++ "/addition.h" });

        // Ensure the commands run in order .. not a given otherwise
        gen_run1.step.dependOn(&gen_run0.step);
        gen_run2.step.dependOn(&gen_run1.step);
        gen_step.dependOn(&gen_run2.step);

        b.default_step.dependOn(gen_step);
    }


Not sure what you're looking for as if you really want to, you can define some helper function in your build.zig to combine steps. Other than that, it's pretty neat that you don't need make only zig build.

nope. addSystemCommand is your best. Besides that you  just have to go to std.fs.cwd().makeDir and addSystemCommand. You can put them all into a single step that is a function in the build: https://gist.github.com/layneson/e0ed54f9e14da878dd0ba102da41e2c3
